# ASP.Net Core "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException" in some sites but not others

Tags: c#, asp.net

Code to create json files that works on some projects is failing on all new projects.

Running as Administrator doesn't help.

Help please!

All new ASP.Net Core MVC projects I create are unable to create files in local directories.  The code that fails is:

```
string _physicalPath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Files"), "tblTxt.json");
using (StreamWriter writer = System.IO.File.AppendText(_physicalPath))
{
    writer.WriteLine("log message");
}
```

The result on all new projects is:
{System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\Files\tblTxt.json'.
   at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
   at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append)
   at System.IO.File.AppendText(String path)
   at WebAutomation.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) in C:\Users\patri\source\repos\WebAutomation\WebAutomation\Startup.cs:line 25}

Comment: I would start by making sure the directories that are being accessed have proper permissions. Add IIS_IUSRS to the security for those folders.

Comment: Are you opening a file on local machine or on a remote machine or File Server?  It looks like the issue is probably a Group Policy that isn't allowing you to open a file on a remote machine.  Normally to open a remote file you use G$ where the dollar sign indicates you are using admin privileges.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share

Comment: IUSR has full control in permissions on the folder on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

firstly
 Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Files") is not good
Pass string to it like this

```
var t = Path.Combine("D:", "DOWNLOADS","abc");//==>D:\DOWNLOADS\abc
```

secondly Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() giving you 
'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\Files\tblTxt.json'.

```
Check if "Files" directory exists in "C:\Program Files\IIS Express" using 
"Directory.Exists()"
if it dosent exist then  create one using   "Directory.CreateDirectory()"
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\Files")
```

Comment: Based on your idea, I changed my code as follows:

            string logfilePath = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "logs", "tblTxt.json");

            string _directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(logfilePath);

            if (!Directory.Exists(_directoryPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(_directoryPath);
            }

Comment: Hi, Did it worked ? [ if you are working with  "C:\Program Files\"  as env.ContentRootPath  ,  in win 10 we dont have much acess to "C:\Program Files\" we have to take ownership if we want to  access it......  ]